# Bundle applescript into application from the command line

Tags: macos, command-line, applescript

I can compile an applescript file into an application from the applescript editor, but I would like to be able to do this from the command line.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/osacompile -o /path/to/applicationbundle.app /path/to/textfile.txt
```

run `man osacompile` for more info.